# Postgres 10 and partitioning by week

Tags: partitioning, psql

i'm trying to understand how partitioning works, and main manual doesn't help me a lot.

Also, `PostgreSQL 10` supports partitioning natively... but what does it mean?

is it possible to declare table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.audit_logs (
        log_type varchar(31) NOT NULL,
        id int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('audit_logs_id_seq'::regclass),
        additional_data varchar(1024) NULL DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
        week int NOT NULL DEFAULT date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
        CONSTRAINT audit_logs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
        OIDS=FALSE
)
PARTITION BY  (week) ;
```

and how to create auto tables `public.audit_logs_N`, where N would be week number?

Do i need to create a trigger? 
or what?

Comment: IMHO you should add the `year`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> main manual doesn't help me a lot.

I hope you've read the manual, both entries:

[ddl_partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) (& the Limitations `5.10.2.3. Limitations`)

[create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

If yes, please mention specifically what you don't understand about it.

> partitioning natively... but what does it mean?

You don't have to create check constraints, trigger functions or triggers.

The SQL example above needs to be modified thusly:

```
e07=# CREATE TABLE public.audit_logs (
        log_type varchar(31) NOT NULL,
        id serial NOT NULL ,
        additional_data varchar(1024) NULL DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
        week int NOT NULL DEFAULT date_part('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
PARTITION BY list  (week) ;

--catch this error in the code:
--ERROR:  no partition of relation "audit_logs" found for row
```

> and how to create auto tables public.audit_logs_N, where N would be week number?

Depending on the requirements, create the partitions in advance or use a pgagent (or crontab) to create them one at a time in the prior week.

```
create table audit_logs_not_1 partition of audit_logs for values in (1);
...
create table audit_logs_not_53 partition of audit_logs for values in (53);
```

> Do i need to create a trigger? or what?

A trigger is only needed for [Implementation Using Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION-INHERITANCE)

Comment: thank you, now i have some confidence in building simple partitions.